# unable to connect to the database keep getting an unusual error

Tags: php, pdo

I have created a class of DB and called that class on a page but I do not know what the problem is I  keep getting an unusual error, found the similar issues on Google but couldn't have solved this problem.

This is the error :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

Here is my db class

```
class db {
    private $host;
    private $db_name;
    private $db_user;
    private $db_password;

    public function connect() {
        $db_name = $this->db_name;
        $db_user = $this->db_user;
        $db_pass = $this->db_password;
        $db_host = $this->host;

        $db_name = 'database name';
        $db_user = 'username';
        $db_pass = 'password';
        $db_host = 'localhost:3306';

        try {
            $connect = new PDO('mysql:dbname=$db_name;host=$db_host;', $db_user, $db_pass);
            $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo "Connection Successfull";
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "Connection Failed : " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I am using to test if this is only a warning or it is a failed connection to the data base

```
$users      = new users();
    $connection = new db();
    $connect    = $connection->connect();
    $sql = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
    $sql->execute();
    while($data = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $data['name'];
    }
```

Comment: I doubt the way to specify a connection port is `$db_host = 'localhost:3306';`. That will most likely lead to mentioned error, since that is _not_  a resolvable host name. Instead the port needs to be specified separately, _if at all:_ since 3306 is the standard port you do not need to specify it anyway. So change the host name to only "localhost" (without a port number) and all should be working.

Comment: the single quotes don't interpolate/use the variables - with that code you are connecting to a machine called '$host', not the value of the variable. #1 debugging tip - print what is actually happening, not what you think must be.

Comment: so I should use localhost instead localhost:3306

Comment: PHP Warning:  PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in public_html/agent/classes/connection.php on line 20 still the same

Comment: @AlisterBulman could you please let me know what shoudl i print to see what exactly is happening ?

Comment: @UsmanKhan If you need to specify the port (i.e. if it's any port **except** the standard port of 3306), you need to use the form `mysql:dbname=$db_name;host=$db_host;port=$port`.

Comment: @Mike not working either with same when i used this to connect using msqli it is working perfectly fine i do not know when i changed as class it is then not working

Comment: Because you didn't read @AlisterBulman's comment, most likely.

Comment: Your code is broken in the ways both Alister and Mike are saying, but also move that `setAttribute()` call into [the constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) [as the `$options` array] and it will actually throw an Exception when it breaks.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: @AlisterBulman please post as answer as your provided information helped me out but also after fixing the queries was not working but when i returned the $connect variable it worked is it necessarily to return connection variable as well?

Comment: @dakis Yes I have my issue is resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single quotes (in `... new PDO('mysql:dbname=$db_name;host=$db_host;', ...`) don't interpolate/use the variables - with that code you are connecting to a machine called '`$host`', not the value of the `$host` variable.

My #1 debugging tip - print what is actually happening, not what you think must be - it's surprising how often something looks obviously right, but is clearly incorrect when properly shown what is actually being delivered to the system.

As for the `$connect = $connection->connect();` line, yes - you need to `return $connect;` out of the function. That variable is what allows you to access the PDO functionality - it has the information within it about actually being able to talk to the database server. (In this instance, sending the SQL that you are first `prepare`-ing).

Comment: thank you so much for your help in future will be more carefull about this mistake